# Extends a RouteCollection object for Web Form routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I use asp.net 4 and web forms in c#.

I would like to know how to Extends a `RouteCollection Class` for **Web Form** routing.

As MSDN state RouteCollectionExtensions Class is avaialbe only for MVC routing.
So I would like to know how an equivalent in Web Forms.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Routing is available for webforms in .NET 4, and 3.5 I think.

There is guidance on MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

The webforms example requires you to add the following in `global.asax`

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
       "Category/{action}/{categoryName}",
       "~/categoriespage.aspx");
}
```

The `RouteCollectionExtensions` type provides extension methods which extend `RouteCollection` for the MVC framework, you can create your own [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to extend `RouteCollection`.

Simple example below, i'm sure you will want to put `MyRouteCollectionExtensions` somewhere else.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Routing; 

namespace WebFormsExtension 
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
        {
            routes.MapCustomRoute("SampleRoute/{name}"); 
        }

    }

    public static class MyRouteCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static void MapCustomRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string url)
        {
            PageRouteHandler handler = new PageRouteHandler("~/default.aspx");
            Route myRoute = new Route(url, handler);    
            routes.Add(myRoute);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I understand your point but I need do smt different. Look at http://goneale.com/2008/12/19/lowercase-route-urls-in-aspnet-mvc/ I need implement in Asp.net Web Forms instead of MVC and because RouteCollectionExtensions Class is avaialbe only for MVC routing I thought would make sense Extend RouteCollection  let me know your thoughts thanks on this

Comment: I think your getting confused by the type name, there is no reason why you can't use that sample. The `RouteCollectionExtensions` class in that sample is not the same as the `System.Web.MVC.RouteCollectionExtensions` class, the author has created his own class with the same name as the MVC one, you can call it whatever you like `MyRouteCollectionExtensions` in my example above. We do something almost identical for lower case Urls in WebForms.

Comment: OK I see your point, just last question how would I use your code in method Page.GetRouteUrl? thanks for your time on this :-)

Comment: `Page.GetRouteUrl(new { name = "Bob" });` would give you `/SampleRoute/Bob` - but my code is only to demonstrate how extend `RouteCollection`, follow the blog post. As an alternative you could have specified a name for the route (`routes.Add("TestRoute", myRoute);`) then passed that as the first parameter of `Page.GetRouteUrl("TestRoute", new { name = "Bob" })`. I recommend having a read through the MSDN pages, they have some great documentation that explains how it all works.